# How to convert xml to valid json string

Tags: ios, json, xml, bash, parsing

I have some XML I would like to feed into an api endpoint, however, I need to convert the xml to a json valid string in order to do so.  When I search online for converting xml to JSON or "JSON valid string" I am finding parsers that convert the xml to a json object with the same structure as the xml.  I want something different, I want to convert the xml into a string that will be used as a single value in a json dictionary.

This means I need to convert new lines into "\n".  Also the result needs to pass JSON lint validation.  https://jsonlint.com.

For example, lets say I have the following swift code:

```swift
import UIKit
import TableMVVM

class SubMenuChoice: NibView, HasViewModel {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var viewToGradient: BottomLeftToTopRightGradient!

    var viewModel: ViewModel = .fallBack {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel.text = viewModel.titleText
            self.detailsLabel.text = viewModel.detailText
            self.viewToGradient.layer.cornerRadius = 16
            self.viewToGradient.clipsToBounds = true
            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        }
    }
}
```

I then convert it to a valid one line json string by swapping out the new lines for literal carriage returns.

```
{"MyJSON" : "import UIKit\nimport TableMVVM\n\nclass SubMenuChoice: NibView, HasViewModel {\n\n    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!\n    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!\n    @IBOutlet var viewToGradient: BottomLeftToTopRightGradient!\n\n    var viewModel: ViewModel = .fallBack {\n        didSet {\n            self.titleLabel.text = viewModel.titleText\n            self.detailsLabel.text = viewModel.detailText\n            self.viewToGradient.layer.cornerRadius = 16\n            self.viewToGradient.clipsToBounds = true\n            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor\n            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderWidth = 0.2\n        }\n    }\n}\n"}
```

[image]

Here is the text I need to convert into a single line, valid json string value:

```
import UIKit
import TableMVVM

class SubMenuChoice: NibView, HasViewModel {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var viewToGradient: BottomLeftToTopRightGradient!

    var viewModel: ViewModel = .fallBack {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel.text = viewModel.titleText
            self.detailsLabel.text = viewModel.detailText
            self.viewToGradient.layer.cornerRadius = 16
            self.viewToGradient.clipsToBounds = true
            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.viewToGradient.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        }
    }
}

extension SubMenuChoice {
    struct ViewModel: HasFallBack {
        let titleText: String
        let detailText: String

        static var fallBack: Self {
            .init(titleText: "-", detailText: "-")
        }
    }
}

///// Interface builder XML, .xib  /////
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="19529" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="19519"/>
        <capability name="Image references" minToolsVersion="12.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <customFonts key="customFonts">
        <array key="Inter-Regular.ttf">
            <string>Inter-Regular</string>
        </array>
    </customFonts>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="SubMenuChoice" customModule="QRCodeTarot" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="detailsLabel" destination="cA5-NT-4u9" id="g9z-Bi-iPU"/>
                <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="Apr-Ou-WfJ" id="cAU-7I-Tk1"/>
                <outlet property="viewToGradient" destination="UG4-zb-Meg" id="cPu-gS-ndd"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="409" height="127"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UG4-zb-Meg" customClass="BottomLeftToTopRightGradient" customModule="QRCodeTarot" customModuleProvider="target">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="393" height="111"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" alignment="center" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yCu-Vd-yGa">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="353" height="71"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="top" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="IbF-c7-i6X">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="12" width="323" height="47.5"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Game 1" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Apr-Ou-WfJ">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="60" height="21"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Inter-Regular" family="Inter" pointSize="17"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Short Description of game. " textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cA5-NT-4u9">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="29" width="194.5" height="18.5"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Inter-Regular" family="Inter" pointSize="15"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" red="0.70196078431372544" green="0.70196078431372544" blue="0.70196078431372544" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </stackView>
                                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fmD-Uj-nrG">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="331" y="25.5" width="22" height="20"/>
                                    <color key="tintColor" red="0.70196563010000002" green="0.70195221900000004" blue="0.70196127890000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="22" id="5nL-F4-TDg"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="fmD-Uj-nrG" secondAttribute="height" id="TJa-x2-MQi"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="22" id="zxE-9d-IP3"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                    <imageReference key="image" image="chevron.right" catalog="system" symbolScale="default"/>
                                    <preferredSymbolConfiguration key="preferredSymbolConfiguration" scale="default" weight="semibold"/>
                                </imageView>
                            </subviews>
                        </stackView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.094216383989999999" green="0.097880952059999998" blue="0.1137293801" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                    <accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration" hint="GradientRoundedbox" identifier="GradientRoundedbox" label="GradientRoundedbox">
                        <bool key="isElement" value="NO"/>
                    </accessibility>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="yCu-Vd-yGa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="UG4-zb-Meg" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="3RX-6j-jOS"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="yCu-Vd-yGa" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="EO3-94-kqy"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="yCu-Vd-yGa" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="UG4-zb-Meg" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="ZqU-CK-TE2"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="yCu-Vd-yGa" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="j7q-UD-Mtj"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="UG4-zb-Meg" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="2oh-y3-hqC"/>
                <constraint firstItem="UG4-zb-Meg" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="97v-Yx-mRr"/>
                <constraint firstItem="UG4-zb-Meg" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="eJq-NG-K3S"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="UG4-zb-Meg" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="yw9-bW-Zza"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="128.2608695652174" y="-143.63839285714286"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="chevron.right" catalog="system" width="96" height="128"/>
    </resources>
</document>


///// Unit tests  /////

Import XCTest

class SubMenuChoiceTests: XCTestCase { 
    
    
}
```

When I try to just swap out the new lines with new line literals it breaks the JSON linter.

[image]

I suspect I'm not the first person to do this kind of thing, so I'm hoping someone knows the formula to convert xml to a valid json string.  PLease help.  Thank you.

Comment: Coud you please clarify what does "it breaks the JSON linter" mean? Does the linter produce an error? If it does, what error is it?

Comment: There are more characters than just newline that have to be escaped in JSON strings.

Comment: `jq -cn --rawfile xml foo.xml '$xml'` if jq is available for your environment.

Comment: There is no "formula" for this, because there are hundreds of ways of converting XML to JSON, all of which end up representing the same information in different ways. If you're starting with a specific XML format and want to produce a specific JSON format, then you typically need to write some conversion logic "by hand" - often XSLT 3.0 can be a convenient tool for this.

Comment: I guess I'll mostly write it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with github.com/mikefarah/yq

```bash
yq -n --indent=0 '.MyJson = load_str("file.txt")' -o=json
```

This will create a new JSON document, loaded with the string contents. It will automatically escape characters.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: Cool.  I’ll give it a go when I circle back to this project.  Thank you.